# Find a control in Windows Forms by name

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am working on an application which add objects (basically [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) controls) at run time from an XML file. The application needs to access the objects that have been added.

The objects are added in a panel or in a groupbox. For the panel and groupbox, I have Panel.Controls["object_name"] to access the objects. This is only helpful when the object is directly added on the same panel. In my case the main panel [pnlMain, I have access to this panel only] may contain another panel and this panel [pnlChild] again contains a groupbox[gbPnlChild] and the groupbox contains a button [button1, I want to access this button]. I have the following method for this:

```
Panel childPanel = pnlMain.Controls["pnlChild"];
GroupBox childGP = childPanel.Controls["gbPnlChild"];
Button buttonToAccess = childGP["button1"];
```

The above method is helpful when parents are known. In my scenario, only the name of the object is known that is to be accessed [button1] and not its parents. So how do I access this object by its name, irrelevant of its parent?

Is there a method like GetObject("objName") or something similar?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the form's [Controls.Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find) method to retrieve a reference back:

```
        var matches = this.Controls.Find("button2", true);
```

Beware that this returns an *array*, the Name property of a control can be ambiguous, there is no mechanism that ensures that a control has a unique name.  You'll have to enforce that yourself.

Comment: Is it a case-sensitive search?

Answer (score 5):

If you are in a user control and don't have direct access to container form you can do the following

```
var parent = this.FindForm(); // returns the object of the form containing the current usercontrol.
var findButton = parent.Controls.Find("button1",true).FirstOrDefault();
if(findButton!=null)
{
    findButton.Enabled =true; // or whichever property you want to change.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  TextBox txtAmnt = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtAmnt" + (i + 1), false).FirstOrDefault();
```

This works when you know what you are loking for.

Comment: The +1 in the expression saved me from a bug!

Answer (score 2):

The .NET Compact Framework does not support Control.ControlCollection.Find.

See [Control.ControlCollection Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection_methods%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and note that there is no little phone icon beside the Find method.

In that case, define the following method:

```
// Return all controls by name 
// that are descendents of a specified control. 

List<T> GetControlByName<T>(
    Control controlToSearch, string nameOfControlsToFind, bool searchDescendants) 
    where T : class
{
    List<T> result;
    result = new List<T>();
    foreach (Control c in controlToSearch.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Name == nameOfControlsToFind && c.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {
            result.Add(c as T);
        }
        if (searchDescendants)
        {
            result.AddRange(GetControlByName<T>(c, nameOfControlsToFind, true));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
// find all TextBox controls
// that have the name txtMyTextBox
// and that are descendents of the current form (this)

List<TextBox> targetTextBoxes = 
    GetControlByName<TextBox>(this, "txtMyTextBox", true);
```