# converting string to a control name in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find a control in C# winforms by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483912/find-a-control-in-c-sharp-winforms-by-name)

Imagine that we have 4 textBoxes (and a button):

> textBox1:( Here we must enter the name of the textBox where we want to change
>   background)
>
> textBox2:()
>
> textBox3:()
>
> textBox4:()

In our first textbox we enter a name of any other TextBox and when we click on a button - backrground will change accordingly.

Normally I'd do something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string variableName = textBox1.Text();

if (variableName == "textBox1")
{
    textBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
else if (variableName == "textBox2")
{
    textBox2.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
else if (variableName == "textBox3")
{
    textBox3.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
else if (variableName == "textBox4")
{
    textBox4.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
}
```

Another way - **much simpler** way do the same operation would be this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string variableName = textBox1.Text();
    variableName.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

And that's all! So my question is:

Is it possible to convert strings to "control names" as showed in example?

Comment: You use `this.Controls.Find`, see the question I've flagged as a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A **very optimist** approach would be

```
this.Controls.Find("variableName", true)[0].BackColor
```

Comment: `.Find` is not populating in VS for me :/

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge do you have `using System.Linq;` on you file?

Comment: not working...Error:object not set to instance...i have provided a correct control ID too

Comment: @Syed This error means that the control wasn't find, thus it's returning null. Could you post some of you code?

Comment: thanks it's working

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
var txtBox = this.Controls.Find("textBox4", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Dictionary<string, TextBox>` where the name of each TextBox in the Dictionary is the key for that TextBox.

Then it would be as simple as `TextBoxDictionary[variableName].BackColor = Color.Black;`, although I recommend checking to make sure it is actually in the dictionary before doing that.