# How to find a text box by name and write its contents to a text file

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find a control in C# winforms by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483912/find-a-control-in-c-sharp-winforms-by-name)

I will try to explain it.. So I have a for loop, and each time I want to load the textbox number equal with the cycle integer.

Here is my code:

```
for(int i=1 ; i<=indulok+1 ; i++)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("futamok/"+comboBox1.Text + "/" + indulok + ".txt");
    sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    sw.Dispose();
}
```

Now I want to replace textBox1.Text to something like this:

```
sw.WriteLine(textBox + i + .Text);
```

But this is not working of course.

Comment: The question in title isnt very good sorry! (My english...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an alternative that would find the control by name.

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= indulok + 1; i++)
        {
            if (this.Controls.ContainsKey("textBox" + i.ToString()))
            {
                TextBox txtBox = this.Controls["textBox" + i.ToString()] as TextBox;
                if (txtBox != null)
                {
                    string FileName = "C:\\" + i.ToString() + ".txt";
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(FileName, txtBox.Text);
                }
            }
        }
```

If your control is nested inside other controls (ie. a GroupBox), you may need to use the Find function

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= indulok + 1; i++)
        {
            Control[] controls = this.Controls.Find("textBox" + i.ToString(), true);
            if (controls.Length > 0)
            {
                TextBox txtBox = controls[0] as TextBox;
                if (txtBox != null)
                {
                    string FileName = "C:\\" + i.ToString() + ".txt";
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(FileName, txtBox.Text);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am sorry my question is misunderstandable. So I dont want to change the textbox's texts, I want to save the serveral textbox texts to serveral files ( textbox1.text to 1.txt, textbox2.text to 2.txt )

Comment: I've updated the solution to write the values to their own text files.  I put them in C:\1.txt in the sample but you can change the path to anything you want

Comment: This second code doesn't save anything at all :/

Comment: I'm sorry, it was Controls.Find("txtBox" + i.ToString(), true)  but it was supposed to be Controls.Find("textBox" + i.ToString(), true)

I've updated the code to reflext this.

Comment: Thank you very much, now its working! I will be a programmer, maybe 10 years later! :D

Answer (score 3):

You can put your textboxes into some sort of indexed collection.  the simpelest of which is an array

so, assume you had some array like

```
textBox[] textBoxes
```

then you can call

```
sw.WriteLine(textBoxes[i].text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running some sort of Windows Forms-project? If you are, you can loop the Controls-array to find all textboxes:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == textBox1.GetType())
        sw.WriteLine(c.Text);
}
```