# Change the Textbox1.text to Textbox2.text

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Let's say I have multiple `TextBoxs` and I want to concatenate numbers like this. Then, I want to add some text on it. Is this possible to do somehow?
This is what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    string str = "Textbox" + i.ToString();
    str.Text = "testing";
}
```

I am not sure how to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Write down an example, your question is not clear.

Comment: You can find control by its name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510065/how-to-find-a-text-box-by-name-and-write-its-contents-to-a-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use the [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings)

> An interpolated string looks like a template string that contains interpolated expressions. An interpolated string returns a string that replaces the interpolated expressions that it contains with their string representations.

**Example:**

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    str = $"Textbox{i}";
    str.Text = "testing";
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're using C# 6.0 or above, since it was introduced in that version.

Comment: This will not help. `str` is still just a string. The OP wants a `TextBox`

Answer (score 0):

Well, Here is another method that you can use, you will have to keep track of all the text boxes in your form and add them to a global list.

```
Dictionary<string,TextBox> texts = new Dictionary<string,TextBox>();
```

On your **FormLoad** do this

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
       texts.Add(c.Name,(TextBox)c);
```

and whenever you want to get any textbox, do this

```
 TextBox targetBox;
 texts.TryGetValue("textBox1", out targetBox);
```

Your for loop will look like

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    string str = "Textbox" + i.ToString();
    TextBox targetBox;
    texts.TryGetValue(str, out targetBox);
    targetBox.Text = "testing";
}
```

An advantage to this approach is your entire textbox(any control for that matter) collection is in a dictionary so you can look-it-up even if the text boxes do not follow a generic naming scheme.