# How to find a listview by name in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms form on which there are a few listview controls. Currently, if I ever need to add some changes to those listviews, I have to specify all names in my code. It is troublesome if I have to list a few names at each time. So I am wondering if there is a way to retrieve a listview control just by providing a name string. Something like:

```
Controls.find(name of listview)
```

I tried

```
Controls.Find(name,true)
```

But it returns an error. What is the reason?

Comment: And what error did you get?

Comment: Maybe this answers it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483912/find-a-control-in-c-sharp-winforms-by-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example will work, just be aware that it is case sensitive and returns a ControlCollection.

```
var tmp = Controls.Find("ListView1", true);
```

[image]

Comment: oh i see what's wrong now, the upper case is causing issue, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Control[] controls =  Controls.Find("listView1", true);
ListView control = controls[0] as ListView;
```