# Compact Framework 3.5 referencing user control error

Tags: vb.net, controls, compact-framework, ctype

I have a compact framework application [vb.cf] running on windows CE platform. I have a user control that I add multiple times to my to my form , to form a grid, in run-time.

I am now trying to access and set the properties on my user controls and using the ;

```
Dim mod_prop As ctl_mod_table = CType(Me.pnl_table.Controls("ctr_" & icount), ctl_mod_table)
```

This produces the following error :

`Conversion from string "ctr_1" to type integer is not valid???`

Any reason why I get this?

I DO NOT WANT TO USE A LOOP ALL CONTROLS procedure as this is slow.

Comment: Why not just keep your controls in a list so you don't have to find it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Compact Framework you must search the controls by name manually.  [This SO question has a CF-specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483912/find-a-control-in-c-sharp-winforms-by-name).

Comment: this.Controls.Find is not support by cf.net [compact framework]. this is my underlying problem. :(

Comment: As Chris said, look at the specific answer talking about Compact Framework!

Answer (score 0):

your `Controls(...)` is using an index value, so an integer. Here you are trying to pass a string variable, `ctr_1`, which is obviously... not an integer.

You need to access your control by its name, try simply to call `Me.Controls("ctr_" & icount)` instead of `Me.pnl_table.Controls("ctr_" & icount)`: you will look at the controls of the form.

Comment: Thanks for this. The reason I use me.pnl_table.controls is because my user controls are inside a panel called pnl_table. Does this makes a difference?

Comment: his.Controls.Find is not support by cf.net [compact framework]. this is my underlying problem. :( –