# How to refer to a variable with a string format?

Tags: c#, repeat

A lot of times i want to **automate** some statements by using string formatting, but unfortunately it doesn't work !

*for example if i have this code :*

```
Textbox1.Text = "";
Textbox2.Text = "";
Textbox3.Text = "";
```

*how can i achieve the same results by doing something like this :*

```
for ( int i = 1; i < 4; ++i )
    string.Format( "Textbox{0}.Text", i ) = "";
```

the code above is completely wrong, my goal was to make the question clear .

**Update : basically referring to a variable with a string**

Comment: Create an array/list of TextBoxes

Comment: Widows forms or asp.net?

Comment: @stuartd : thanks for the reply, anything even if it's a console application

Comment: How about using Hashtables?!!

Comment: There are no controls in a console app.

Comment: Nobody seems to understand the question. All he wants is to refer to a variable with a string. That string could be built with string.Format. As far as I know, it's not possible. But I don't know everything. Maybe some shenanigans with reflection would make it possible. I don't know.

Comment: You've obfuscated for security too much - to tell us you want to mess with textboxes and then say it's a console application.  Programming's all about automating - what do you want exactly and why can't you achieve it?

Comment: BTW, for strings the assignments could be chained: `Textbox1.Text = Textbox2.Text = Textbox3.Text = "Some string";`. But if you have quite a few controls to work with then I'd go with a `List<>` and call `ForEach`

Comment: @Pluc thank you Pluc, you described  exactly what i want !

Comment: @CindyH all i want is to refer to a variable with a string

Comment: You can access fields by using reflection, and check their names that way, but it would be awfully slow.

Comment: @CindyH - fields, but not variables. So reflection will not help OP according to "i want is to refer to a variable with a string" comment.

Comment: If suggested duplicate not enough - this search http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+refer+to+variable+by+index will give you more options.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you, i'll search more .

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net, you can use the FindControl method of the parent control to these textboxes.  Such as:

```
for ( int i = 1; i < 4; ++i )
    (Page.FindControl("Textbox" + i) as Textbox).Text = "";
```

Comment: great, what about if they were not textBoxes ? i mean something else not of type Control !

Comment: Well everything in asp.net inherits from Control.  If it's not a textbox then you can cast it to whatever you want.

Comment: Is as operator better than a simple cast in this case?

Comment: Great solution.  But when using the FindControl, remember that it's recursive - you have to start with the outermost control, then loop through all of its children, etc.  If there's a textbox inside a panel, it won't be found when you just look at the controls on the window.  But you can do great stuff with a recursive control formatter - I have in the past but no longer have access to the code.

Comment: @CindyH - Yes, good to point this out.  Usually I put my controls in a parent panel.  Then I do Panel1.FindControl("txt1") etc. if you want to skip the recursive route.

Comment: @Ben - "as" vs a cast would be about the same in this situation.  "as" will return null if the cast operation fails, rather than raising an exception.

Comment: Ok. I wasnt aware of the difference; thanks.

Comment: For WinForms, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4483962/1378739)

Answer (score -3):

You can use `dynamic`:

```
    class Whatever { public string Text { get; set; } }
    class It { public string Text { get; set; } }
    class Can { public string Text { get; set; } }
    class Be { public string Text { get; set; } }

    static void Main()
    {
        var whatever = new Whatever();
        var it = new It();
        var can = new Can();
        var be = new Be();

        foreach (var item in new dynamic[] {whatever, it, can, be})
            item.Text = item.ToString();
    }
```

But you should enumerate processing items in any case and know property/method names in the compile time. Otherwise, go ahead and use reflection.