# Get all controls with names that start with specific string

Tags: c#, winforms, search, controls

For a school project we are creating a C# application where children can learn.

I made a template in the windows form and want to change the  placeholder with the choice of the child, so it can become 1x choice, 2x choice, etc.

I gave every label a name that starts with `tafel_noemer_` - `tafel_noemer_1`, `tafel_noemer_2`, etc.

Now I want to select all those labels up to label 10 and change the placeholder text. I tried `this.Name.StartsWith("tafel_noemer_")` but can't get it to work with foreach.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

[image: my Form]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find control by name from Windows Forms controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls) and [Find a control in WinForms by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483912/find-a-control-in-winforms-by-name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Linq's where method:

```
foreach (Label l in this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(l => l.Name.StartsWith("tafel_noemer_")))
{
    l.Text = "bla bla";
}
```