# Is it possible to write text into a textbox with the help of textbox name in C#?

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to write some text into a textbox whose name is based on num1 and num2 as mentioned in the code. so, if num1 and num2 are 0, 0 then the text should be written to a textbox with name 'textbox00' similarly if num1 and num2 are 1, 1 then the text should be written to 'textbox11'. Is this possible?

```
int num1;
int num2;
if (num1 == 0 && num2 == 0)
{
  //Write some text into textBox with name $"textbox{num1}{num2}"
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: NameOfYourTextBox.Text = "your text ";

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find control by name from Windows Forms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls) and [Get all controls with names that start with specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877904/get-all-controls-with-names-that-start-with-specific-string)

Comment: Thanks for the link. This looks similar to my question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

what i understand you want to select specific textbox based on **num1** & **num2** values

you can do it by using the below code

```
  if (num1 == 0 && num2 == 0)
    {
        var textbox = Controls.Find("textbox" + num1+ num2  , true).FirstOrDefault(); 
     
    if (textbox != null) 
    { 
        textbox.Text= "Your text"; 
    }   
}
```