# How can i take the values from texboxes by the name of it

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want the following code to give me the exact number of S values from the textboxes named : **Box1_1 , Box1_2 , Box1_3, Box1_4, Box1_5 ...**

But when i try to see the value it's always blank. What can i do ?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++){
        string box = "Box" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
        TextBox nameBox = new TextBox();
        nameBox.Name = box;
        if(string.Compare(nameBox.Text, "S")==0){
            numberS++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I guessed your question correctly then you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483912/find-a-control-in-windows-forms-by-name. You have to find the control by its name then compare the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cheeky little one-liner using `Linq` (split over multiple lines for clarity):

```
var textBoxes = this.Controls
                    .OfType<TextBox>() // controls that are TexteBoxes
                    .Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Box") && t.Text.StartsWith("S"))
                    .ToList();

int numberS = textBoxes.Count();
```

- We get all `TextBox` controls using `OfType<TextBox>()`
- This assumes the name of the TextBoxes you're interested in start with `"Box"`. The corresponding Linq is `Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Box"))`.
- It looks like you're only interested in the TextBoxes that have a value that starts with `"S"`.  The corresponding linq is `Where(t => t.Text.StartsWith("S"))`.  I have combined these in a single `Where`.
- Then we get the count: `.Count()`
- If you want the count of textboxes that contain `S` (not just start with `S`) then use `t.Text.Contains("S")` in the `Where` clause instead.

---

If you want to get the `TextBox` names (`Box1_1`, `Box1_2`, etc) then you can use `Select` which will take the `Name` property from each `TextBox` and return a `List<string>`

```
var txtNames = this.Controls
                   .OfType<TextBox>() // controls that are TexteBoxes
                   .Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Box") && t.Text.StartsWith("S"))
                   .Select(t => t.Name)  // select textbox names
                   .ToList();
```

`txtNames` is a `List<string>` containing the textbox names which start with `S`.

Comment: This works, but i need the positions where the S is located.

Comment: @ReD See my update - `TextBoxes` is a list of all the textboxes that contain `S`.  Iterate through them to get the names/positions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a collection of your TextBox'es or scrap them from your window. Example of how to do the second is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/9258059).

Here is your code that I modified:

```
public int CountS()
        {
            var numberS = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
                {
                    string box = "Box" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
                    TextBox nameBox 
                        = UIHelper.FindChild<TextBox>(Application.Current.MainWindow, box); //using example linked above
                        //= textBoxes.First(tbx => tbx.Name == box); //if you got collection of your textboxes
                    numberS += nameBox.Text.Count(c => c == 'S'); //if you wont also count a small "s" add .ToUpper() before .Count
                }
            }
            return numberS;
        }
```

Comment: Do I need anything else? Because the UIHelper doesn't work.

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow` is for WPF.  The question was tagged WinForms.